# unable to access gridview html checkbox on button click event it's show "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nullreferenceexception

I am unable to access html checkbox on button click event.The checkbox is in gridview control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="_grvItems" runat="server"  />
              <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <input type="checkbox"  id="_chkSelect" />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

And I click on button then show me error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
the code of button click event is :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _grvItems.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox ch = (HtmlInputCheckBox)_grvItems.Rows[i].FindControl("_chkSelect");

        if (ch.Checked)
        {
            Response.Write("Checkbox is Checked");
        }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

The `FindControl` method is *not* returning the `checkbox` but returning `null`. This is why you are getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." When you would be accessing `Checked` property. You need to put `runat="server"` to make checkbox server accessible.

*Change*

```
 <input type="checkbox"  id="_chkSelect" />
```

*To*

```
 <input type="checkbox"  id="_chkSelect" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply
but when i put runat="server" than show me this error "The server tag is not well formed".

Comment: Actually i am already call javascript function on checkbox check event
"<input type="checkbox" onclick="setToday('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("_txtMinQty").ClientID %>');" />"

Comment: Adding runat="server" will make it accessible in code behind, whats wrong with that? Do you still have problem?

Comment: I have no clue what problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check for null:

```
HtmlInputCheckBox ch = (HtmlInputCheckBox)_grvItems.Rows[i].FindControl("_chkSelect");

if (ch!= null && ch.Checked)
{
    Response.Write("Checkbox is Checked");
}}
```

**EDIT (As [Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298762/adil) pointed:**

I would also change in markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="_grvItems" runat="server"  />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>    
                <input type="checkbox"  id="_chkSelect" runat="server" />    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please change in markup also as I have shown in edit, and let us know in which line you are getting error.